# How to read number tokens inside a string to a two dimension vector

Tags: arrays, c

My string in c looks like this, it contains 9 numbers each separated by a comma like

```
91,86,94,12,54,88,79,58,66
```

and a two dimension array with three ***ROWS*** and three ***COLS***, I wish to assign these numbers to the array up to the last index of the two dimension array, I have tried the code below but when i print the elements of the matrix afterwards, I see crazy numbers;

***CODE***

```
  char* replaced="91,86,94,12,54,88,79,58,66";
  //Define the two dimension array
  int ROWS=3;
  int COLS=3;
  //assign memory to the array
  int (*matrix_array)[ROWS] = malloc(sizeof(int[ROWS][COLS]));
   //initialize all members to zero
    memset(matrix_array,0,sizeof (matrix_array));
   //split the string into tokens
   char delim[2]=",";
   //ge the first token
    char* token= strtok(replaced,delim);
    //get the remaining tokens
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for(int j =0;j<COLS;j++){
            while(token!=NULL){
                //parse an integer out of the token
                int sub=atoi(token);
                 //assign the number to the array
                matrix_array[i][j]=sub;
                 //update the token for the while loop
                token=strtok(NULL,delim);
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I use the code below on the matrix_array to check the assignment, I see big numbers , please help

```
for(int row=0;row<ROWS;row++){
   for(int col=0;col<COLS;col++){
    printf("%d\n",matrix_array[row][col]);
   }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot compile. `matrix_array` is defined *twice*. And fyi, `replaced` is erroneously pointing a pointer-to-non-const-char to a read-only string literal, which has disaster written all over it if you're tokenizing that (which writes to the source buffer). To that, consider your while-token loop, which will consume *all* of the tokens, writing every one of them into `matrix_array[0][[0]`

Comment: It sure can compile after the changes I introduced, I ommitted the memset snippet

Comment: So it will assign a single number to all the indices?

Comment: Compiling means syntactically correct; it doesn't mean the *logic* is correct. The issues I pointed out are severe. Some of it can be caught early by turning on full warnings enabled and treating them as errors. And no, it will assign *all* the tokened values to `matrix_array[0][0]`, one at a time, until `token` is null, then each successive advance through the matrix will encounter `token` is null, and do nothing. In short, ask yourself why `while(token!=NULL)` isn't `if(token!=NULL)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig, what changes do you propose I add to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're consuming all your tokens on the first-row/first-column cell. From there on out, there are no more token. the biggest hint of this is that the *last* value in the input is the *only* value that appears to have actually been parsed, and its in `[0][0]`.

Fixing that, and a plethora of other issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char replaced[] = "91,86,94,12,54,88,79,58,66";
    // Define the two dimension array
    int ROWS = 3;
    int COLS = 3;
    // initialize all members to zero
    int(*matrix_array)[COLS] = calloc(ROWS, sizeof *matrix_array);
    // split the string into tokens
    char delim[] = ",";
    // ge the first token
    char *token = strtok(replaced, delim);
    // get the remaining tokens
    for (int i = 0; token && i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; token && j < COLS; j++)
        {
            matrix_array[i][j] = atoi(token);;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix_array[row][col]);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }

    free(matrix_array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
91 86 94 
12 54 88 
79 58 66
```

Frankly, I'd also use `strtol` to convert your values, but I leave that as an exercise to you.

Comment: whats ***DIM_GRID_8***?

Comment: There are quite a few changes in this, and all of them are important, so review it *carefully*. Ex: note the early exit in both loops when `token` reaches null (if it does so prematurely). Also note that `matrix_array` is correctly using `COLS` for the inferior dimension.

Comment: Okay thanks, lemme try it and see if I get any thing positive

Comment: it worked, c is challenging, its very different and its not even OO, though I will try to master it